# Wordpress: Display posts by custom select query

Tags: wordpress

I need to get posts by custom category id, sort by custom field value and with another custom field if this field exists. I think I need to use custom selection query. Look at my query: The problem is that this query returns the same post 5 times... In admin panel I made 20 posts per page. Maybe someone have their own solution ? Thanks.

```
$wp_query->request = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id)
WHERE $wpdb->terms.slug = 'categoryname'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request, OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$customSelect = new WP_Query(array(

    'post_type'       => 'post',      
    'posts_per_page'  => 10,
    'taxonomy'        => 'category',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'meta_key'        => 'your custom field',
    'orderby'         => 'meta_value'
```

This is probably way off what your trying to achieve, the only bit I can't get my head round is how to test if meta key exists using a variable or something.

Anyways good luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need one more meta_key, because I want to orderby meta_value of meta_key, And I need to check another meta_key if it exists.

Comment: Sounds pretty tricky, sure you will find an answer here for a small amount. http://www.wpquestions.com/

Comment: +1: old post but just saved me from having to write a custom sql query to order some posts by a meta tag.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you use "$wp_query->request", this variable is for retrieving last query result, not to set new one...

just try

```
$my_custom_sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id)
WHERE $wpdb->terms.slug = 'categoryname'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($my_custom_sql, OBJECT);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Try this-

   get_results( 
   "
   SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
   LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
   ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
   LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
   ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
   WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
   AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
   AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 3
   ORDER BY post_date ASC
   "
   ); ?>